# Are there examples of explicitly-notated, precise, nontrivial polytempo before Ives and Nancarrow?

Tags: notation, rhythm, tempo

Polytempo refers to the simultaneous use of two or more distinct tempi in a piece of
music. Polyrhythm can be viewed as a special case of polytempo; any polyrhythm can be written as a temporary tempo change.

For this post, an instance of polytempo is "trivial" if one or both of the following is true
for the entirety of the polytemporal section:

- Measure onsets always coincide in all tempi (as would happen with 3/4 at 90 bpm against 2/4 at 60 bpm).
- There are only two tempi and the ratio between them (or its reciprocal) reduces to 2:1,
  3:2, or 4:3.

(Note that these conditions are unrelated to meter.)

An instance of polytempo is "precise" if the relationship between the different tempi is
specified exactly.

As far as I am aware, Charles Ives's Symphony no. 4 is the earliest work featuring
polytempo that is both nontrivial and precise. (The polytempo in Ives's *Central Park in
the Dark* is not precisely indicated.) Conlon Nancarrow would fully explore polytempo a
few decades later. Are there any examples of explicitly-notated, precise, nontrivial polytempo before Ives? Or by composers other
than Ives before Nancarrow?

Comment: 6/8 and 2/4 both have two beats per measure, so if 6/8 and 2/4 have different b.p.m. then the measures have different durations.  Perhaps 3/4 and 2/4 would be a better example.

Comment: @phoog You're right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Donald Byrd's page on the [extremes of conventional music notation](https://homes.luddy.indiana.edu/donbyrd/CMNExtremes.htm) simply cites Gardner Read's *Modern Rhythmic Notation* (1978) when it discusses polymeter.  From the description, Read's book does appear to contain examples, so it might be worth perusing it if you have access to it;  but there may not be much specifically talking about polytempo.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I have the book. It discusses polytempo only in passing; there's no dedicated section for the topic. But it's a great resource for polymeter.

Answer (score 5):

The first piece that comes to mind is Johannes Ockeghem's [missa prolationum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missa_prolationum).  This piece is entirely written on mensural canons: different parts sing the same notes at different speeds.  As the example in the Wikipedia article shows, the first Kyrie is a double mensural canon.  There are two written parts, each of which is sung by two voices, the ratio of their tempi being 2:3.  The slower voice of one part is effectively as fast as the faster voice of the other part, more or less as though one is in 3/2 and the other in 6/4 with the measures having the same duration, so you could say that the ratios are 4:6:6:9.

Another piece that comes to mind, but which may not satisfy the requirements of the question, is the Act 1 finale of Mozart's *Don Giovanni,* which begins as a minuet in 3/4.  While that continues, one group of instruments begins playing another dance in 2/4, and then a third group [switches to a fast 3/8](https://youtu.be/tREevio8ux8?t=257).  The quarter note of the 2/4 and the dotted quarter of the 3/8 are equal to the quarter note of the 3/4, so the measures have different lengths.  I almost did not include this example because it's three different meters at one tempo, so arguably not polytempo, but I decided to mention it because you say that polyrhythm is a subset of polytempo, and this polymeter does result in polyrhythm.

Comment: The Missa meets the criteria. I'm more interested in examples after modern metric notation came into being, but it seems there aren't any.

Answer (score -1):

Ives is the first obvious one - although relatively unknown at the time, so others came up with the same idea independently, rather than being influenced by him.

However - you could include just about all African drumming - abeit not notated.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't provide any new information.

Comment: It talks of travelers here, could that include notated music as well https://www.britannica.com/art/African-music ?